# Geonetwork metadata title length

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, css, title

In geonetwork I have truncated metadata file title when I do a search. Sometimes it is only a few characters that are missing so I try to increase the number of characters that can be displayed. 
in the `gn_search_default.less` file located in `/catalog/views/default/less` folder there are the options for the title.

```
gn-md-title {
      margin-top: 2px;
      min-height: 3.5em;
      max-height: 3.5em;
      overflow: visible;
      cursor: pointer;
      h3 
      {
    /* Leave space for selection checkbox */
    //padding-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    a {
      //text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 80%;
      color: #333333;
      max-width: 800px;
      overflow: visible;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: #428bca;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}
```

I can change the font-size percentage for instance but the max-width has no effect. I removed the `text-overflow: ellipsis` option and set `overflow: visible`.
However it has no effect on the displayed length of the title.

Here is a screenshot of the website in Firefox.

Any idea how to modify that?

[image]

Comment: Could you add the link again, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the truncated title via CSS. As you can see in the following screenshot, the text of the `<a>` element is truncated programmatically by the platform. (You can reach this view by right-clicking on the title and then choosing "Inspect element".)

[image: Screenshot of a search in Geonetwork]

The `title` attribute of the `<a>` element describes the tooltip that appears when you hover over the `<a>` element.

---

That said, you can easily remove the truncation by editing `catalog/components/search/resultsview/partials/viewtemplates/grid.html`. Simply change [line 65](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/49f351ca03503e7bcbcc3cc3745766364b18875a/web-ui/src/main/resources/catalog/components/search/resultsview/partials/viewtemplates/grid.html#L65) from

```html
<a data-ng-href="#/metadata/{{md.getUuid()}}"
  title="{{md.title || md.defaultTitle}}">
  <i class="fa gn-icon-{{md.type[0]}}" title="{{md.type[0] | translate}}"/>
  {{(md.title || md.defaultTitle) | characters:80}}
</a>
```

to

```html
<a data-ng-href="#/metadata/{{md.getUuid()}}"
  title="{{md.title || md.defaultTitle}}">
  <i class="fa gn-icon-{{md.type[0]}}" title="{{md.type[0] | translate}}"/>
  {{(md.title || md.defaultTitle)}} <!-- remove the "character" modifier -->
</a>
```

Comment: that's sad... Thx

Comment: See my edit. I don't really know Geonetwork, but you will have to rebuild the platform in some way if you modify the HTML.

Comment: Yes that could make the trick. I need to think about possible erase of my changes when new version of geonetwork are release though. Thanks for your time.